# How to compare each element in array to one single value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, javascript-objects

I have an `array` with multiple `objects` inside.
It's structured like that:

```
const Instructor = [
  { ID: '141',
    InstructorNameAR: 'test',
    InstructorNameEN: 'Mohamed Ahmed',
    InstructorBriefAR: 'phd in chemistry',
    InstructorBriefEN: 'phd in chemistry' },
  { ID: '140',
    InstructorNameAR: 'test',
    InstructorNameEN: 'Mahmoud Ahmed',
    InstructorBriefAR: 'phd in chemistry',
    InstructorBriefEN: 'phd in chemistry' },
]
```

I wanted to add other `objects` but filtered of duplicates based on their `ID` values.

Example of `objects` i want to add :-

```
  const InstructorInstance = {
    ID: 'ID',
    InstructorNameAR:   'NAMEAR',
    InstructorNameEN:   'NAMEEN',
    InstructorBriefAR:  'BRIEFAR',
    InstructorBriefEN : 'BRIEFEN'
  }
```

I used this method to filter by `ID`.
But it didn't work as it compares only a `single` value of the `array` to the value i provided. which means it might be a `duplicated object` but still gets added because it did not check if it exists in each `array element`

```
Instructor.forEach(instance =>{
  if(instance.ID !== InstructorInstance.ID){
    Instructor.push(InstructorInstance);
  }else{
    console.log('Duplicate')
  }
})
```

Comment: what is the ideal way of comparison you have in your mind then? check all fields (case sensitive/insensitive)? if that is the case, why not simply add a check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to loop the whole array first before deciding whether there is a duplicate or not. You can use `forEach` for that but `every` or `some` seem like the perfect fit for this kind of job:

```
const test = Instructor.every(instance => instance.ID !== InstructorInstance.ID);
if(test) {
    Instructor.push(InstructorInstance);
}
```

Which means if every object in `Instructor` has a different `ID` than `InstructorInstance`, then push `InstructorInstance` into `Instructor`.

**Note:** You can put the test directly inside `if` without having to store it in a variable `test`:

```
if(Instructor.every(instance => instance.ID !== InstructorInstance.ID)) {
    Instructor.push(InstructorInstance);
}
```

But that doesn't look, does it?

Comment: It worked. Thank you!

Comment: You're very welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `some` to check if that object already exists, if not, add it:

```
if (!Instructor.some(i => i.ID == instance.ID)) {
    Instructor.push(instance);
}
```